# PHP/MYSQL Echo Mysql Data with hyperlink onto next page?

Tags: php, mysql

In my table I have various requests each with their own reference number.
a user can see the number of requests on the page, but I want the user to be able to click on each request separately and be taken to a new page to see the specific details for that request.

I am trying to echo the reference in a hyperlink when the request is clicked and on the next page when I run my query to retrieve the name etc of that request it will only show the information which matches that reference number, i.e. `'SELECT * WHERE reference = $row['reference'].`

However I am not sure on how to to do this, also I am concerned is this secure, if my query is checking against the reference in my url, i.e. `mypage.php?reference=1234`, whats to stop a user just manually typing in the url with a different reference number?

```
'mypage.php?reference=2468
```

the user should only be able to view the page if they actually clicked on the request, they should never be able to enter it directly into the url as this poses a security risk.

could I potentially mask my reference into a string? and echo out `mypage.php?reference=$someString`

page1.php

```
<div class="results_area">
                <h44>Existing Supplier Request's</h44>  
    <?php 
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 
    $sql = "select * from new_supplier_request where status!= 'complete' AND action_taken='actioned'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo '<div class="table_header"><p>Request By</p><p>Date Requested</p><p>Status</p><p>Supplier Name</p><p>Description</p><p>Action</p></div>'; ?> 
                </div>

                <div class="results_area"><?php
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 


                echo '<div class="request"><a href="ns_application.php?ns_request='.$row['reference'].'/">';
```

mypage.php

```
$reference = $row['reference'];

<?php 
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 
$sql = "select * from new_supplier_request where status!= 'complete' WHERE reference = $reference Limit 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            echo '<h44>New Supplier Request: &nbsp;' .$reference. ' </h44><br>'; 
            echo 'The name of this supplier is, '.$reference['name'].';
} } ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use a session variable to hold information about the user, and check that they're allowed to view the reference number they request.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use JavaScript to solve this problem.
I don't think that this will be 100% secure but actually it's more secure way than you are using now.
echo "<div .... onclick='showuniquereference('".$row['reference']."')'>"."</div>";

And Function like this
function showuniquereference(code)
{
var reference = code;
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "mypage.php";
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.name = "reference";
input.value = reference;
input.type = "hidden"; 
form.appendChild(input);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}

You can use this posted data to show unique reference to users.
```